# Symfony 1.4 sfThumbnail not generating thumbnails

Tags: php, file-upload, symfony-1.4, thumbnails, symfony-forms

I have an upload form, it works well, the photo is being uploaded but the problem is that the sfThumbnail plugin doesn't seem to work. No thumbnail is being generated. Here's my code:

```
      // /lib/form/UploadForm.class.php

      public function configure()
      {
      $this->setWidget('photo', new sfWidgetFormInputFileEditable(
      array(
        'edit_mode' => !$this->isNew(),
        'with_delete' => false,
        'file_src' => '',
         )
      ));

      $this->widgetSchema->setNameFormat('image[%s]');

      $this->setValidator('photo', new sfValidatorFile(
        array(
        'max_size' => 5000000,
        'mime_types' => 'web_images', 
        'path' => '/images/',
        'required' => true,
        'validated_file_class' => 'sfMyValidatedFileCustom'
            )
       ));
```

And here's for the validator class

```
    class sfMyValidatedFileCustom extends sfValidatedFile{

    public function save($file = null, $fileMode = 0666, $create = true, $dirMode = 0777) 
    {
      $saved = parent::save($file, $fileMode, $create, $dirMode);
      $thumbnail = new sfThumbnail(150, 150, true, true, 75, '');
      $location = strpos($this->savedName,'/image/');
      $filename = substr($this->savedName, $location+15); 
      // Manually point to the file then load it to the sfThumbnail plugin
      $uploadDir = sfConfig::get('sf_root_dir').'/image/';
      $thumbnail->loadFile($uploadDir.$filename);
      $thumbnail->save($uploadDir.'thumb/'.$filename,'image/jpeg');
      return $saved;
    }
```

And my actions code:

```
    public function executeUpload(sfWebRequest $request)
    {
    $this->form = new UploadForm();
    if ($request->isMethod('post'))
    {
      $this->form->bind(
        $request->getParameter($this->form->getName()),
        $request->getFiles($this->form->getName())
      );
      if ($this->form->isValid())
      {
           $this->form->save();
           return $this->redirect('photo/success');
      }
    }
     }
```

I'm not 100% sure if I am doing it correctly but this is what I have seen from the docs and other examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `$this->savedName` because it's a protected value from `sfValidatedFile`. You should use `$this->getSavedName()` instead.

I don't understand this part:

```
$location = strpos($this->savedName,'/image/');
$filename = substr($this->savedName, $location+15);
```

Why do you extract the filename, when, finally, you re-add `/image/` to it when load it with `loadFile`?

Any way, I made some change on your class. I didn't tested it but I think it should work.

```
class sfMyValidatedFileCustom extends sfValidatedFile
{
  public function save($file = null, $fileMode = 0666, $create = true, $dirMode = 0777) 
  {
    $saved    = parent::save($file, $fileMode, $create, $dirMode);
    $filename = str_replace($this->getPath().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, '', $saved);

    // Manually point to the file then load it to the sfThumbnail plugin
    $uploadDir = $this->getPath().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

    $thumbnail = new sfThumbnail(150, 150, true, true, 75, '');
    $thumbnail->loadFile($uploadDir.$saved);
    $thumbnail->save($uploadDir.'thumb/'.$filename, 'image/jpeg');

    return $saved;
  }
```

Comment: thanks so much j0k! you are a life saver! Thanks for the detailed explanation as well. I'll be sure to keep that in mind.